# Is there a way to repeat the code from previous line in Jupyter Notebook? like a short cut key?

Tags: python, jupyter, shortcut

[image: image here]

I am using miniconda, and may be that is an issue, but i want to be able to repeat previously ran codes like we can do with up arrow key in Terminal or CMD prmpt.

Comment: Use `CTRL + Z` and `CTRL + Y`

Comment: This did not work. thank you though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.